# Bug in conversion of net/gross prices

Tags: mysql, math, rounding, rounding-error

In my project the user input for prices can be net or gross, depending on a configuration value. In database we save the net price as decimal(9,2), the VAT and a flag for the price to know if is deductible or not.

For example conversion from gross to net (that most users use):

VAT = 19%

| Gross Price (user input) | Net Price (saved in Database) |
| --- | --- |
| 1500 | 1260.50 |

But revert conversion to user input is not the same:

| Net Price (saved in Database) | Gross Price (user input) |
| --- | --- |
| 1260.50 | 1499.99 |

Saving the cents in database, will not solve the problem.

Saving the gross price in database is a bad practice and will imply a big data migration when the VAT changes.

Rounding the gross price for user will also not help, because it will generate calculation errors for the total price.

Please help...

Edit:

Another example (database price column is double):

| Gross Price (user input) | Net Price (saved in Database) |
| --- | --- |
| 19500 | 16386.554621848 |

Reverted conversion:

| Net Price (saved in Database) | Gross Price (user input) |
| --- | --- |
| 16386.554621848 | 19499.999999999 |

Comment: Can you store the net price to a higher precision e.g. 1260.504201? If you ever need the net price to the nearest cent, you can apply rounding at the point it is needed, so it will return 1260.50 as required, but when you calculate the gross price you still get 1500.

Comment: That's arithmetic for you. I suggest you store the base price and the vat rate.

Comment: Once you crop the result to 2 decimal places (like you normally would for currencies) the information required to reproduce the original number is gone.

Comment: @GarethD It is ok in 98% cases, but how about the 2%? The clients complain that the prices are not correct.

Comment: @P.Salmon Am i not?

Comment: @SalmanA I know! :) What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: @Mirela what exactly is the tax rate and how many decimal digits you have (or legally required to have) in it?

Comment: @Mirela If you also round your gross price when you need it there is no issue - 19499.99999999 rounded to the nearest cent is 19500, which matches the user input. [Example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7j39cdu2rUGKuA6Mr1YvgM/0)

Comment: @SalmanA The tax rate (VAT) is 19. It could also have 1 decimal digit, for example 19,6.

Comment: You could even add these as calculated columns so that you don't need to bother with the rounding every time they are needed, e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7j39cdu2rUGKuA6Mr1YvgM/2

Comment: @GarethD I'll try your solution in my project!

Answer (score 2):

***Revised answer:***

It is not a bug but a roundoff error. You seem to be performing a division operation `1500 / (119 / 100)` and storing the result in a fixed point datatype. Unfortunately, like in the above example, the result will contain infinite many digits after decimal (enter the above example on [wolframalpha.com](https://wolframalpha.com/) to see what I mean). When you use the truncated value to reproduce the original value, it will not match.

Unfortunately, the only thing you can do is to increase the scale of the `net` column. This will not eliminate the error, but it will decrease its magnitude. Then use the `ROUND` function for accounting purpose and for recreating the original value.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=096e9811d6b1ad14ae2a1e76f1807763)

Comment: I tried your solution, but i got the same result... [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=485671f0ecc9b03a9a5a446c556dd38f)

Comment: @Mirela You just need to round the result to the same precision as it is stored - [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a13df6e60ebe375e842f80bdb7a209d8)

Comment: @Mirela in the fiddle you're using division so this changes things unfortunately. You'll need at least 6 digits. Still, this will not take care of cases where you have values such as 1/3 etc.